# Practical to use row-major order in Maple?

Tags: arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, vectorization, maple

Apparently Maple has sort of a pragma-like option called *[order](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Fortran_order)* which allows you to change the default column-major ordering of rtables internally to row-major order.

I am wondering how practical this is. Won't your code be incompatible with all the built-in libraries and so forth? Also, I would expect such code to be incompatible with any colleague or collaborator algorithms that are not row-major. So, it would seem to be completely impractical to use this option, except for some special purpose, like doing a data export to C. Is that right?

Comment: You make it sound as if column major is a nearly universal default. That's not true AFAIK. Both orders are in common usage.

Comment: Furthermore, the order option only makes a small difference (about 4%) in the efficiency of the code; it does change the usability of the code.

Comment: So, you are saying, that a multi-dimensional algorithm, like say a singular value decomposition, written for row-major will work on a column major system in Maple? I don't get that?

Comment: If elements are accessed in the correct order, then it very likely that the next entry needed is already in cache (faster) memory. If the matrix is organized in the opposing order to the algorithm, it is much more likely (for a large matrix) that the next entry will be fetched from the main (slower) memory. But that next entry can nonetheless still be fetched.